# Convert multiple quad strips into single quad strip

Tags: opengl, mesh

I want to convert the five quad strips in the figure below (which are specified be the black indices below) into a single quad strip by adding appropriate degenerate quads. The added gray indices seem to do the trick, but I am wondering if there is a more compact way.
[image]

Comment: Those aren't quad strips; they're tri-strips.

Comment: No, these a quad strips. Any OpenGL quad strips also specify tri-strips.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using degenerate triangles, you should be using [primitive restart](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Rendering#Primitive_Restart). With this, you simply specify that a particular index restarts a primitive. The core OpenGL 3.1 version is several years old, and the NV_primitive_restart extension is widely supported by NVIDIA (since the GeForce 6xxx days) and ATI (all HD-class hardware).

Comment: I'd rather use degenerates since this is more widely supported. I want to know if I can do it with less indices.

Comment: Primitive Restart isn't supported on Open GL ES or WebGL.

Comment: @rickster: Yes, and if he'd *asked* about OpenGL ES or WebGL, I wouldn't have mentioned it. The "OpenGL" tag is for *desktop* OpenGL, not everything with the "GL" name. Also, ***Quads*** aren't supported on GL ES or WebGL either. So the question *couldn't* have been about them.

Answer (score 1):

If it absolutely must be quad strips, then I believe there is nothing else to be done (beside the already-mentioned primitive restart).  However, if you are willing and able to use triangle strips (which I would strongly encourage), it would result in a small improvement.

The *true* indices are identical for a quad strip and the equivalent triangle strip, so there's nothing to lose in that respect.  However, a quad strip restart requires *two* stop indices and *two* start indices.  A triangle strip restart only requires *one* stop index and *one* start index.

In the original example, with three restarts, this would shave off six indices.